# I want to display div when hover on anchor tag by css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display div when hover on anchor tag by CSS. This is my code but not working. Also I want to display the div with slow-motion by CSS.

```css
#shoow {
  display: none;
}
#hoverMe:hover #shoow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hoverMe">ShowDetails</a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="shoow" style="width: 650px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what does " my code but not working" mean?

Comment: _"I want to display div"_ -- I don't see any `div` in your code.

Comment: The css would only work if #shoow was a child of #hover me. As thats not the case I dont believe its possible with css alone

Comment: Your CSS `#hoverMe:hover #shoow` says that when you hover `#hoverMe` display the **child element** with the id of `#shoow`. Your HTML structure does not follow your rule, or should I say, your CSS doesn't work with your HTML structure.

Comment: i am sorry <td> not display

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your second selector to:

```
#hoverMe:hover + table #shoow {
  display: block;
}
```

What you have now, `#hoverMe:hover #shoow`, tries to look for an element with the ID shoow as a descandant of an element with the ID of hoverMe, which it isn't. However if you use the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) or the sibling selector (`~`) it will work.

```css
#shoow {
  display: none;
}
#hoverMe:hover + table #shoow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hoverMe">ShowDetails</a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="shoow" style="width:650px;height:100px;background-color:blue;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do css transitions on the display property as it's either on or off, to make it slower just add more before the s's in thoe transition property.

```css
#shoow {
  . . .
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}
#hoverMe:hover + table #shoow{
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hoverMe">ShowDetails</a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="shoow" style="width:650px;height:100px;background-color:blue;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```